# How to select xml element based on its attribute value start with "Heading" in xslt?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

I want to call my own xsl template whenever i found the matching of xml element that having its attribute value starting with "Heading". How do I make this query in Xslt.

For example:

```
<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
     <w:pStyle w:val="Heading2"/>
  </w:pPr>
</w:p>

<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
     <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/>
  </w:pPr>
</w:p>

<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
     <w:pStyle w:val="Heading2"/>
  </w:pPr>
</w:p>

<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
     <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>
  </w:pPr>
</w:p>

<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
     <w:pStyle w:val="commentText"/>
  </w:pPr>
</w:p>
```

So, I want to make query that w:pStyle -> w:val starting with "Heading" only.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can achieve this by making use of the XPath string function starts with

```
<xsl:template match="w:pStyle[starts-with(@w:val, 'Heading')]">
```

This simply matches all **w:pStyle** nodes where the **w:val** attributes starts with the word **Heading**. You can then put your own code in this template.

Here is an example of how you would use it in the XSLT identity transform

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:w="http://mynamespace.com">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="w:pStyle[starts-with(@w:val, 'Heading')]">
      <!-- Your code here -->
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above XSLT, unless you did add you own code where it says, would strip out all mathcing **w:pStyle** elements from the XML.